# In Moose, how to specify constructor arguments for the superclass in a subclass?

Tags: perl, moose

I have a Moose class with some properties (`x`,`y`,`z`). I subclass it, and for the subclass, `x` is always 3. How can I specify this in subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could use [`BUILDARGS`](https://metacpan.org/dist/Moose/view/lib/Moose/Manual/Construction.pod).

```perl
around BUILDARGS => sub {
    my $orig  = shift;
    my $class = shift;
 
    return $class->$orig(@_, x => 3 );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I used to work with Moo but it seems to be the same. You just need to declare the property in the subclass using `+` to override previous declaration.

```perl
package Foo;
use Moose;
 
has 'a' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Num',
);

has 'b' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Num',
);

has 'c' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Num',
);


package My::Foo;
use Moose;
 
extends 'Foo';
 
has '+a' => (
    default => 3,
);
```

Comment: If it really is *always* 3, then `has '+a' => ( is => 'ro', default => 3, init_arg => undef );`